# Nasm: xor register with qword

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, xor

A basic question:
Why is it possible to xor two 64 bit registers with eachother (two qwords) and not xor a 64bit register with a qword.

So this works:

```
mov rax, 0x1234567812345678
mov rbx, 0x8765432187654321
xor rax, rbx
```

But this doesn't:

```
mov rax, 0x1234567812345678
xor rax, 0x8765432187654321
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because the 64-bit ISA has not been extended to have 64-bit immediates (since this make the instructions very long).  However, the (still) 32-bit immediates are sign extended, but in general you need to `xor` two registers.

Comment: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XOR.html - find the "imm64" one... yep, none.

Comment: Thanks for the reactions! Margaret, please make yours an answer :P. Let me add that I am an absolute newbie in assembly so I did not know that the duplicate question would be the same as my question, so sorry for that.